# PHP error when using Low Variables with Grid and Assets

Tags: assets, grid, low-variables, php-errors

I created a Low Variable, using a Grid field. One of the Grid columns is an Assets field. It actually all works as supposed to. Except that I get an annoying PHP notice:

```
Severity: Notice
Message: Array to string conversion
Filename: assets/ft.assets.php
Line Number: 1778
```

Is there a way to resolve this?

Some example code

```
{exp:low_variables:pair var="low_var_grid"}     
    {low_var_grid:grid_assets_col}
        <img src="{low_var_grid:grid_assets_col:url}">
    {/low_var_grid:grid_assets_col}
{/exp:low_variables:pair}
```

Setup

```
EE 2.9.2
Low Variables 2.5
Assets 2.5
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, this definitely is an Assets issue, but here's a temporary fix.

Open up ft.assets.php and look up the `grid_replace_tag` method, around line 1771. In there, you can see this line of code:

```
$field_name = ee()->db->select('field_name')->from('channel_fields')->where(array('field_id' => $this->field_id))->get()->row('field_name');
```

Below that, add this:

```
if ( ! $field_name)
{
    $field_name = ee()->db->select('variable_name')->from('global_variables')->where('variable_id', $this->field_id)->get()->row('variable_name');
}
```

...which should fix the issue.

Comment: Fixes the issue for me to.

Comment: This fix worked for me too

Comment: Still seems to be an issue with what are currently most recent version of Assets 2.5 on EE 2.10.1. This fix still works though. Thank you for providig this, Low.