# Assets and Low Variables not compatible?

Tags: assets, pixelandtonic, low-variables, low

When I add an assets field to a Low Variable, it reports that it's added it correctly, however I then get a fatal error whenever I try to load the LV dashboard:

`Unable to load the requested file: field/field.php`

If I manually delete the row in the table, LV returns to normal operating status and all is fine.

Similarly, if I add an Assets field to a grid Low Variable, I don't get the above fatal error, however I get the following PHP errors:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Array to string conversion
Filename: libraries/Core.php
Line Number: 409

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/--REDACTED--/system/codeigniter/system/core/Exceptions.php:170)
Filename: core/EE_Security.php
Line Number: 88

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/--REDACTED--/system/codeigniter/system/core/Exceptions.php:170)
Filename: core/EE_Security.php
Line Number: 89
```

Has anyone else seen these problems and is there a hotfix available to resolve it?

I'm running `ExpressionEngine 2.9.2` and `Assets 2.5`

Assets in a channel entry works fine, so the bug seems to be with the compatibility with Low Variables.

---

UPDATE: The second error reported now appears to be happening on ALL assets modal windows within channels *and* with Low Variables.

Comment: This might help with some of the errors: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/28985/php-error-when-using-low-variables-with-grid-and-assets

Comment: Hi Dierderik, No - the problem is in the backend, not the front-end. I tried doing proposed fix, but it didn't do anything in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Appears the problem was a conflict with another custom add-on that was installed. I've disabled it for the time being and I'll review the source code to fix at a later date.

Comment: what add-on it was?